# Show that there exists a $\alpha \in \mathbb{C}$ for which $\alpha f: V \rightarrow V$ is an isometry.

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, isometry

Task:
Let $(V,\langle.,.\rangle)$ be a unitary vector space, $f \in \operatorname{Hom}_{\mathbb{C}}(V, V)=\operatorname{End}_{\mathbb{C}}(V) $ an endomorphism $ \neq 0 $ with the property that for all $v, w \in V $with $\langle v, w\rangle=0$ also $\langle f(v ), f(w)\rangle=0 $ holds. Show that there is a $\alpha \in \mathbb{C} $ for which $\alpha f\colon V \rightarrow V $ is an isometry.

Problem:
I've already recorded this visually, but only for $\mathbb{R}^{2}$, for $\mathbb{C}$ I'm not so sure what it looks like. I know that every isometry is either a reflection or more precisely a rotation, but unfortunately I am at the end of my ideas how to show it. Perhaps someone can give me a concrete example of how such a $\alpha$ for $\mathbb{C}$ works, or give me the name of the problem I can look up online.
Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An isometry $g\colon V\rightarrow V$ is a map, that preserves the scalar product, so $\langle g(v),g(w)\rangle=\langle v,w\rangle$ for all $v,w\in V$.

Hint: Consider your map $f\colon V\rightarrow V$, which maps orthogonal vectors to orthogonal vectors, so $\langle v,w\rangle=0\Rightarrow\langle f(v),f(w)\rangle=0$ for all $v,w\in V$.
For any vectors $v,w\in V$ (even if $\langle v,w\rangle\neq 0$), we have:
$$\left\langle v,w-\frac{\langle v,w\rangle}{\|v\|^2}v\right\rangle=0,$$
so this property can be applied and we get:
$$\langle f(v),f(w)\rangle-\frac{\|f(v)\|^2}{\|v\|^2}\langle v,w\rangle
=\left\langle f(v),f\left(w-\frac{\langle v,w\rangle}{\|v\|^2}v\right)\right\rangle=0.$$
So $\alpha=\|v\|/\|f(v)\|$ fits, if we can show, that this value is independent of $v$. Now go back and try, if you could also change the first entry of the scalar product to make it vanish and apply your property.

Comment: Yeah I got $\alpha$ this way: $\langle \alpha f(v), \alpha f(w) \rangle = \langle v, w \rangle \leftrightarrow \langle \alpha , \alpha \rangle \cdot \langle f(v), f(w) \rangle = \langle v, w \rangle \leftrightarrow \alpha = \frac{ \lVert v,w \rVert}{\lVert f(v),f(w)\rVert}$. But I'm kinda stuck about the fact that we can divide by $ \langle f(v), f(w) \rangle$ since this was given to be 0. What am I missing?

Comment: You have to write it a bit different. $\alpha$ is a scalar, so you can just take it out of the scalar product (but with complex conjugation, when you do it for the first entry). So $\langle\alpha f(v),\alpha f(w)\rangle=\underbrace{\alpha^*\alpha}_{=|\alpha|^2}\langle f(v),f(w)\rangle\stackrel{!}=|\alpha|^2\langle v,w\rangle$. If you divide (if it's allowed), then keep the scalar product and don't use $\|-\|$, which is the norm induced by the scalar product and only used, when you put in the same vector $v$ twice, so $\|v\|^2=\langle v,v\rangle$.

Comment: In the above formula, you also see, that you can only find the absolute value of $\alpha$. In fact, a phase factor $e^{i\phi}$ being multiplied to it doesn't matter in the scalar product due to the fact, that if you pull them out, you get a complex conjugation for the first entry, so $\langle e^{i\phi}v,e^{i\phi}w\rangle=\underbrace{(e^{i\phi})^*}_{=e^{-i\phi}}e^{i\phi}\langle v,w\rangle=\langle v,w\rangle$. So you could as well just turn $\alpha$ in the complex plane, so that it is a real positive value. This is what the choice of $\alpha$ in my answer as the quotient of two norms is.

Comment: Okay so for the first entry of the scalar product I have $$\langle f(v- \frac{\langle v,w \rangle}{\langle w,w \rangle} w), f(w) \rangle = \langle f(v), f(w) \rangle - \frac{\|f(w)\|^2}{\|w\|^2} \langle v,w \rangle$$ and $\alpha = \frac{\|w\|}{\|f(w)\|} $ for all $ w \in V$ so $\alpha$ is independent of the choice of $v$. Does that work?

Comment: You have to add a star at $\langle v,w\rangle^*$ in the first term due to complex conjugation, when taking it out of the scalar product. But the result is fine. You see here, that $v$ has been swapped with $w$ in the scalar factor in comparison with my equation. Subtracting both equations gives you $\left(\frac{\|f(v)\|^2}{\|v\|^2}-\frac{\|f(w)\|^2}{\|w\|^2}\right)\langle v,w\rangle=0$. Therefore one of the factors has to vanish, so either $\frac{\|f(v)\|^2}{\|v\|^2}=\frac{\|f(w)\|^2}{\|w\|^2}$ or $\langle v,w\rangle=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Is $V$ finite-dimensional? If so, here is a hint.

I assume that the inner product is linear in the second slot.

---

Suppose that $e_1$, $e_2$, $\dots$, $e_n$ is an orthonormal basis of $V$.

Suppose that $i \neq j$. Suppose that $k$ is a complex number such that $|k| = 1$. Then
$$
\begin{aligned}
& \langle {e_i + ke_j, e_i - ke_j} \rangle \\
= {} & \langle {e_i + ke_j, e_i} \rangle
- k \langle {e_i + ke_j, e_j} \rangle \\
= {} & \langle {e_i, e_i} \rangle + \overline{k} \langle {e_j, e_i} \rangle
- k \langle {e_i, e_j} \rangle
- k\overline{k} \langle {e_j, e_j} \rangle
\\
= {} & 1 - k\overline{k} = 0.
\end{aligned}
$$
Hence
$$
\begin{aligned}
& 0 \\
= {} & \langle {f(e_i + ke_j), f(e_i - ke_j)} \rangle \\
= {} & \langle {f(e_i) + kf(e_j), f(e_i) - kf(e_j)} \rangle \\
= {} & \langle {f(e_i), f(e_i)} \rangle + \overline{k} \langle {f(e_j), f(e_i)} \rangle
- k \langle {f(e_i), f(e_j)} \rangle
- \langle {f(e_j), f(e_j)} \rangle.
\\
\end{aligned}
$$

Hence (in which we take $k = 1$, $-1$, $\mathrm{i}$, $-\mathrm{i}$, respectively)
$$
\begin{aligned}
& 0 
= \langle {f(e_i), f(e_i)} \rangle
+ \langle {f(e_j), f(e_i)} \rangle
- \langle {f(e_i), f(e_j)} \rangle
- \langle {f(e_j), f(e_j)} \rangle,
\\
& 0 
= \langle {f(e_i), f(e_i)} \rangle
- \langle {f(e_j), f(e_i)} \rangle
+ \langle {f(e_i), f(e_j)} \rangle
- \langle {f(e_j), f(e_j)} \rangle,
\\
& 0 
= \langle {f(e_i), f(e_i)} \rangle
- \mathrm{i} \langle {f(e_j), f(e_i)} \rangle
- \mathrm{i} \langle {f(e_i), f(e_j)} \rangle
- \langle {f(e_j), f(e_j)} \rangle,
\\
& 0 
= \langle {f(e_i), f(e_i)} \rangle
+ \mathrm{i} \langle {f(e_j), f(e_i)} \rangle
+ \mathrm{i} \langle {f(e_i), f(e_j)} \rangle
- \langle {f(e_j), f(e_j)} \rangle.
\end{aligned}
$$

We learn from the system of linear equations that
$$
\langle {f(e_i), f(e_i)} \rangle = \langle {f(e_j), f(e_j)} \rangle
$$
and that
$$
\langle {f(e_i), f(e_j)} \rangle = \langle {f(e_j), f(e_i)} \rangle = 0.
$$

Since $f \neq 0$, one of $f(e_1)$, $f(e_2)$, $\dots$, $f(e_n)$ must be nonzero. Without loss of generality, let $f(e_1)$ be nonzero. Let $\ell = \sqrt{\langle {f(e_1), f(e_1)} \rangle} > 0$. Let
$$
u_i = \frac{1}{\ell} f(e_i),
\quad i = 1, 2, \dots, n.
$$
It is not hard to check that
$$
\langle {u_i, u_i} \rangle = 1
$$
and that for $i \neq j$,
$$
\langle {u_i, u_j} \rangle = 0.
$$

I leave it as an exercise for you that you can take $\alpha$ to be $1/\ell$ so that $\alpha f$ is an isometry.